# Entity Framework throws error -Invalid column name 'Id'.\r\n Invalid column name 'Id'."

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

I have the following incoming JSON:

```
  {
    "SampleNumber": "1605",
    "Status": 2,
    "HasPossibleDuplicate": false,
    "ControlType": 1
  }
```

This is my class:

```
  public partial class MyMessage: BaseEntity
  {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SampleNumber", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string SampleNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("HasPossibleDuplicate", Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool HasPossibleDuplicate { get; set; }

  }
```

Base Entity:

```
public partial class BaseEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code to parse incoming JSON and store in respective table.

```
    MyMessage message = DeserializeObject.FromJson(jsondata);
    if (message != null)
    {
     using (var transaction = myContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
     {
       myContext.MyMessage.Add(message);//error comes here
       myContext.SaveChanges();
       transaction.Commit();
     }
    }
```

I get the following exception:

> "Invalid column name 'HasPossibleDuplicate'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Id'."

Comment: "HasPossibleValue " has a whitespace

Comment: no. it was my typo in question. but in actual code I do not have whitespace. updated question.

Comment: Can you post a screen of your table's columns?

Comment: Show your table, This error has nothing to do with json, and for what it is worth, your json property names and actual names in your sample json doesnt match either.

Comment: updated with table image

Comment: @MatJ  Note: I have written different column name in question just for privacy terms of my company policies.  but, anyway now I updated with actual column names.

Comment: Can you post your base entity? It is good to put Id in base entity rather than MyMessage class

Comment: @kudlatiger No problem, but in those cases, make sure names are same everywhere in the code, otherwise such confusion arise. With current update, it seems everything is fine, check if your connections string is pointing to the right db.

Comment: but why Invalid column name 'HasPossibleDuplicate'  error?

Comment: @MatJ  Yes, connection string points to right DB

Comment: As far as I know, this exception is thrown when table exists but it lacks the mapped columns, In sql management studio, there is an option called sql server profiler in tools menu where you can see the sql query that is sent to the db server, check that and see if it sends the right db, table and column names.

Comment: @MatJ you are write. It seems to be pointing different DB! you rock

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question posted by me and found that it has many mistakes. But now I can not delete it because many users contributed to answer this question. Issue is, if I keep this question open, some users are continuing down voting it. so it spoils my points. so help me delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Property **Id** is missing in your JSON and it is required in your database entity class. You can create a separate class (DTO) for your json data and deserialize JSON into newly created class.

```cs
public class MessageDto
{
    public string SampleNumber { get; set; }     
    public string Status { get; set; }     
    public bool HasPossibleDuplicate { get; set; }
    public int ControlType { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
MessageDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageDto>(jsonData);

if (dto != null) {
    MyMessage message = new MyMessage();
    message.SampleNumber = dto.SampleNumber;
    message.Status = dto.Status;
    message.HasPossibleDuplicate = dto.HasPossibleDuplicate;
    message.ControlType = dto.ControlType;

    using (var transaction = myContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
     {
       myContext.MyMessage.Add(message);//error comes here
       myContext.SaveChanges();
       transaction.Commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: My class has 98 properties, so I did not post entire class. In my actual class I do have a 'Id' column, but dto approach seems to be good idea.

Comment: but why Invalid column name 'HasPossibleDuplicate' error?

Comment: @kudlatiger are you mapping MyMessage class as per table name in your EntityFramework DbContext class? Can you share exception stacktrace to get more clarification?